# Implementing an item proportionally in a web page

Tags: resize

I am working with an adaptative design with different breakpoints.
I have a floating fixed object in my page.
I want this object appears less big below a 960px media.
I tried many many codes without success...
My last one is this one but it does not available.

```
<style> 
#imCell_1 {  position: fixed;  right: 20px;  top: 80;  background-color: transparent;  z-index: 6000;  } 
     </style>
 
 <style>

 

    @media (max-width:959.9px)
    #imCell_1.element.style {
        height:70%;
        width:70%;
}
</style>
```

Thanks a lot for your help, I am a beginner with coding and I don't see my mistakes. .
Sincerely,

Danielle

Comment: You also need to supply the html

Answer (score 0):

Found!
Maybe it can help someone...
Solution found is:

```
<style> 
  #imCell_1 { 
    position: fixed; 
    right: 10px; 
    top: 80; 
    background-color: transparent; 
    z-index: 6000; 
  }
</style>

<style> 
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #imTextObject_27_01 {
      height:80%;
      width:80%;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 393px) { 
    #imTextObject_27_01 {
      height:70%;
      width:70%;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Have a nice week.